# After doing CTE Select Order By and then Update, Update results are not ordered the same (TSQL)

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, common-table-expression, sql-order-by

The code is roughly like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT TOP 4 id, due_date, check
 FROM table_a a
 INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.linkid = b.linkid
 WHERE
  b.status = 1
  AND due_date > GetDate()
 ORDER BY due_date, id
)
UPDATE cte
SET check = 1
OUTPUT
 INSERTED.id,
 INSERTED.due_date
```

Note: the actual data has same due_date.

When I ran the SELECT statement only inside the cte, I could get the result, for ex: 1, 2, 3, 4.
But after the UPDATE statement, the updated results are: 4, 1, 2, 3

Why is this (order-change) happening?

How to keep or re-order the results back to 1,2,3,4 in this same 1 query?

Comment: I struggle finding out what you actually are trying to achieve with this, but I doubt the order of data is different but it's more down to your select vs the output clause because your output is not ordered.

Comment: Along [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx),  the order is not guaranted with OUTPUT clause, so you have to replace this OUTPUT with a new `SELECT TOP 4 id, due_date ...`

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen sorry if my question was not clear. I was trying to achieve the same order during the cte select and after the update. I assume that the order will not change after the update.

Comment: @Polux2 Thanks! I was not aware of that information and I just assumed that the order would be the same with cte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177564(v=sql.110).aspx you can read that

> There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied
>   to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the
>   output table or table variable will correspond.

Thats mean you can't solve your problem with only one query. But you still can use one batch to do what you need. Because your output don't guarantee the order then you have to save it in another table and order it after update. This code will return your output values in order that you assume:

```
declare @outputTable table( id int, due_date date);

with cte as (
    select top 4 id, due_date, check
    from table_a a
    inner join table_b b on a.linkid = b.linkid
    where b.status = 1
    and due_date > GetDate()
    order by due_date, id
)
update cte
set check = 1
output inserted.id, inserted.due_date
into @outputTable;

select *
from @outputTable
order by due_date, id;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the fact that there is no guarantee in the order after update. I guess this (one batch) is my only choice to keep the order intact.